# Why is the texture on a model with the mirror modifier asymmetrical?

Tags: texturing, mirror-modifier

[image: screenshot showing asymmetry of model]

Why is the texture on a model with the mirror modifier asymmetrical and how to fix it?

Comment: If you use some Vertex Group, probably it is affected by something ... hard to say just from current screen, but you can test it by Deleting all Vertex Groups you have listed.

Comment: All asymmetries I could see disappeared once I cleaned my screen, can you mark them with circles? Maybe just press Numpad 1 for an exact front (-y) view, then take a screenshot, so I can copy it, flip horizontally and overlay on the original in the difference mode...  

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ... I was also looking for differences a minute :) there is a glitch with eyelid on left side of image.

Comment: @vklidu interesting, I thought it's just a matter of perspective, like here a perfectly mirrored line remains straight on one side but bends on the other https://i.imgur.com/OlNIH4r.gif but thinking of it, in OP's case the change is more prominent.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady What you're describing sounds like triangulation issues, but those shouldn't happen with just a mirror modifier (default triangulation will be symmetrical with a mirror mod.)  For diagnosing your issue or Ksyoush's issue, I would have to see a file.